# Time takes time after install APK first time and then it works fine Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing Xamarin APP. I am a bit new to Xamarin, I am facing a strange issue and I am not able to figure out why I hope there are also few more people in the world who faced the same issue. So they can help to figure out.

**What I am facing:**

I have a timer in my APP, which takes some time if I generate the APK and install the first time on Android device. It take few seconds to start the time on touching it. If uninstall the APP and reinstall the same APK again it will not take time this time. it Start's as I touch it. I am not sure what causes this behavior. Here is my code:

```
private void StartTimer()
    {
        Device.StartTimer(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(UpdateUserDataAsync);
            return true;
        });
    }
  private async void UpdateUserDataAsync()
    {

        if ((totalSeconds - 1) > -1 && MatchStatus == Convert.ToInt32(_matchStatus.Running) && Scoreboard.timerStop == false)
        {
            totalSeconds = (totalSeconds - 1);
            int seconds = (totalSeconds % 60);
            int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60);
            string time = minutes + ":" + (seconds.ToString().Length < 2 ? "0" + seconds.ToString() : seconds.ToString());
            lblTime.Text = time.ToString();
            lblTime.FontSize = 100;
            Scoreboard.GlobalVariableValue = 1;
        }
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.